# Whether $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f)$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(g)$ are isomorphic, with $f,g$ irreducible cubic polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I' trying to check if the claim in the title is true, and my argument is:

If they are isomorphic, then they are isomorphic after a base change to $\mathbb{F}_p$, then I found a prime number $p$ such that $f$ splits completely while $g$ is irreducible mod $p$. Is this enough to conclude that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f)$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(g)$ are not isomorphic? Thanks!

Comment: The OP wrote a clear question, I answered, the answer was accepted, the OP thanked for the explanation and everyone went back to their business. Now after two weeks 5 dudes decided that the question lacks clarity and must be closed. And didn't even leave a comment what exactly is unclear to them. Isn't this ridiculous?

Comment: @Adayah Yes it was also quite confusing for me when the question was closed for lack of details. But anyway it's not deleted, so I hope the question and your answer can still help others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not.

Consider $f(x) = x^3 - 686$ and $g(x) = x^3-2$. Then

$$\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f) \cong \mathbb{Q} \left[ 7\sqrt[3]{2} \right] = \mathbb{Q} \left[ \sqrt[3]{2} \right] \cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/(g).$$

But reducing mod 7 we get

$\overline{f}(x) = x^3 = x \cdot x \cdot x$ and $\overline{g}(x) = x^3-2$ is irreducible because $2$ has no cubic root in $\mathbb{F}_7$.

Comment: The OP's flaw is the (wrong) claim: "*If they are isomorphic, then they are isomorphic after a base change to $\mathbb F_p$*" and your answer provides a counterexample. However the claim holds if one replaces $\mathbb Q$ by $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the comments!